# Calling an inputTask from another inputTask, passing through all input

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I have the following tasks which start and stop something:

```
val doStart = inputKey[Unit]("Starts something.")
val doStop = taskKey[Unit]("Stops something.")
```

Here `doStart` input task accepts some arguments which control the way the thing is started.

Now I want to write a task `doRestart` which behaves like `doStart` but calls `doStop` first. This means that I want `doRestart` to accept the same arguments as `doStart` does, and I don't want `doStart` to run if `doStop` has failed.

The best I was able to come up with is the following definition:

```
val doRestart = inputKey[Unit]("Stops and starts something.")

doRestart := Def.inputTaskDyn {
  val args = Def.spaceDelimited().parsed
  doStop.value
  Def.inputTask {
    doStart.evaluated
  }.toTask(" " + args.mkString(" "))
}.evaluated
```

However, I do not like at all that I have to pass the arguments through manually, especially since I cannot see any way to avoid splitting the input by spaces (I wasn't able to find a parser which just passes the input as a single string). Also, `inputTaskDyn` requires its argument to return an `Initialize[Task[T]]` instead of `Initialize[InputTask[T]]`, so I just cannot return the result of `Def.inputTask`, and `parsed`, when called on `Initialize[InputTask[T]]`, returns `Task[T]`, not `Initialize[Task[T]]`, so I cannot use `parsed` either.

Is there a better way to do it?